# How to share Google Sheets and AppsScript linked to the sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Google Sheet. I have developed an Apps Script which manipulates this Sheet. The Apps Script has lots of different files: a bunch of GS files and a bunch of HTML files.
When I make a copy of the Sheet, I notice that the function:

```
var SCRIPT_PROJECT_KEY_CELL_INDEX = "B2";
var SettingsSheet = "Configuration Settings";
var settings = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(SettingsSheet);
var PROJECT_KEY = settings.getRange(SCRIPT_PROJECT_KEY_CELL_INDEX).setValue(getScriptProjectKey());
```

returns the same value in both the original and the copy of the Sheet.
I also notice a 'make a copy' option under the code editor file menu. When I  create a copy of the code itself, it seems to create a copy - but which spreadsheet would the copy be linked to?

Question I have is how do I make sure that when I send a Google Spread Sheet to one of my clients, the Script associated with that Sheet also get sent and any change or modifications my client does will not affect my original Sheet and Scripts associated with it.

Comment: Please share the complete code as it looks like you are hard coding some key somewhere in the code which is being used and after making a copy nothing will change.

Comment: I don't see that sharing the complete code is relevant here. My question is more to do with copying the Sheet and associated Script all at the same time. I write code for clients. So when client changes their code I want to make sure they change only their copy. At present it is confusing. I am forcing the clients to make a copy of the Sheet - but that does not seem to apply to the Script at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you have created `an embedded app script` then sharing the spreadsheet will lead to sharing of app script code.

However if you have created a `standalone app script` and linked it to a spreadsheet then sharing the spreadsheet will not be sufficient, you have to share the app script as well.

In app script code if you have referenced a spreadsheet by it's key then you will have to change that part of it after making a copy otherwise it will continue to reference the previous key. The same is true if you have used some other key like project id and other keys which needs to be changed after making copy accordingly.

Comment: My question relates to Embedded App Script. I even force copying of the sheet. But still I see that I make change to the Script which is in 'my' original one but the client then complains that his Sheet no longer works - the copying process seems to have copied only the Sheet but not the embedded app script. This is worrying.

Comment: Are you able to confirm that script is not copied after making a copy of spreadsheet ? You can ask your client to open the script editor from the spreadsheet and if you are able to see all the code then code is copied. Also What permissions did you share the spreadsheet with the client ?

Comment: At present only thing I can confirm is that even in the Sheet that my client has copied, it uses the same Project Key as got when one calls the function getScriptProjectKey(). This is the code fragment I pasted here earlier.

Comment: Looks like it was a glitch. Now it is showing a different project key. Throws up questions about reliability though. I don't know how I can explain this to my client. Makes me look bad while it looks like a result of what Google did.